# rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate' (see --tasks)

Tags: ruby

Can anyone help me with ruby on rails. I tried referred many articles regarding this error but could not make it clear yet.I am trying to execute'rake db:migrate' but I am getting
**rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate' (see --tasks)**

Also, I tried to trace it and got following result

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate' (see --tasks)
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:149:in`invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:106:in`each'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:115:in`run_with_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:78:in`block in run'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake/application.rb:75:in`run'
/usr/bin/rake:27:in `'